# ID12LA example code not working on Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino, rfid, nano

I am trying to get the following code running on an Arduino Leonardo (because it has native usb) and it doesn't work. It doesn't even print anything to the serial monitor. When I try it with an Arduino Nano, everything works fine. I have considered whether maybe it is because the softwareSerial library doesn't work with Leonardo, but I couldn't find any information about it online. Anybody has any idea why it doesn't work?

```
    /*****************************
     RFID-powered lockbox

Written by: acavis, 3/31/2015
Modified: Ho YUN "Bobby" Chan @ SparkFun Electronics Inc., 11/10/2017

Inspired by & partially adapted from
http://bildr.org/2011/02/rfid-arduino/

Description: This sketch will move a servo when
a trusted tag is read with the 
ID-12/ID-20 RFID module

----------HARDWARE HOOKUP----------

PINOUT FOR SERVO MOTOR
    Servo Motor ----- Arduino
    GND               GND
    Vcc               5V 
    SIG               D9

PINOUT FOR SPARKFUN RFID USB READER
    Arduino ----- RFID module
    5V            VCC
    GND           GND
    D2            TX

PINOUT FOR SPARKFUN RFID BREAKOUT BOARD
    Arduino ----- RFID module
    5V            VCC
    GND           GND
    GND           FORM
    D2            D0

Optional: If using the breakout, you can also 
put an LED & 330 ohm resistor between 
the RFID module's READ pin and GND for 
a "card successfully read" indication.

Note: Make sure to GND the FORM pin to enable the ASCII output format. 

--------------------------------------------------

******************************/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// Choose two pins for SoftwareSerial
SoftwareSerial rSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

// Make a servo object
Servo lockServo;

// Pick a PWM pin to put the servo on
const int servoPin = 9;

// For SparkFun's tags, we will receive 16 bytes on every
// tag read, but throw four away. The 13th space will always
// be 0, since proper strings in Arduino end with 0

// These constants hold the total tag length (tagLen) and
// the length of the part we want to keep (idLen),
// plus the total number of tags we want to check against (kTags)
const int tagLen = 16;
const int idLen = 13;
const int kTags = 4;

// Put your known tags here!
char knownTags[kTags][idLen] = {
             "111111111111",
             "444444444444",
             "555555555555",
             "7A005B0FF8D6"
};

// Empty array to hold a freshly scanned tag
char newTag[idLen];

void setup() {
  // Starts the hardware and software serial ports
   Serial.begin(9600);
   rSerial.begin(9600);

   // Attaches the servo to the pin
   lockServo.attach(servoPin);

   // Put servo in locked position
   // Note: Value may need to be adjusted 
   // depending on servo motor
   lockServo.write(0);

}

void loop() {
  // Counter for the newTag array
  int i = 0;
  // Variable to hold each byte read from the serial buffer
  int readByte;
  // Flag so we know when a tag is over
  boolean tag = false;

  // This makes sure the whole tag is in the serial buffer before
  // reading, the Arduino can read faster than the ID module can deliver!
  if (rSerial.available() == tagLen) {
    tag = true;
  }

  if (tag == true) {
    while (rSerial.available()) {
      // Take each byte out of the serial buffer, one at a time
      readByte = rSerial.read();

      /* This will skip the first byte (2, STX, start of text) and the last three,
      ASCII 13, CR/carriage return, ASCII 10, LF/linefeed, and ASCII 3, ETX/end of 
      text, leaving only the unique part of the tag string. It puts the byte into
      the first space in the array, then steps ahead one spot */
      if (readByte != 2 && readByte!= 13 && readByte != 10 && readByte != 3) {
        newTag[i] = readByte;
        i++;
      }

      // If we see ASCII 3, ETX, the tag is over
      if (readByte == 3) {
        tag = false;
      }

    }
  }


  // don't do anything if the newTag array is full of zeroes
  if (strlen(newTag)== 0) {
    return;
  }

  else {
    int total = 0;

    for (int ct=0; ct < kTags; ct++){
        total += checkTag(newTag, knownTags[ct]);
    }

    // If newTag matched any of the tags
    // we checked against, total will be 1
    if (total > 0) {

      // Put the action of your choice here!

      // I'm going to rotate the servo to symbolize unlocking the lockbox

      Serial.println("Success!");
      lockServo.write(180);
    }

    else {
        // This prints out unknown cards so you can add them to your knownTags as needed
        Serial.print("Unknown tag! ");
        Serial.print(newTag);
        Serial.println();
    }
  }

  // Once newTag has been checked, fill it with zeroes
  // to get ready for the next tag read
  for (int c=0; c < idLen; c++) {
    newTag[c] = 0;
  }
}

// This function steps through both newTag and one of the known
// tags. If there is a mismatch anywhere in the tag, it will return 0,
// but if every character in the tag is the same, it returns 1
int checkTag(char nTag[], char oTag[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < idLen; i++) {
      if (nTag[i] != oTag[i]) {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  return 1;
}
```

Code is from here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-rfid-starter-kit-hookup-guide/all

Comment: by "I couldn't find any information about it online" you mean you didn't invest more than 5 seconds into it right? because it is actually a matter of typing "leonardo softwareserial" into any websearch engine which seems kind of obvious reading "I have considered whether maybe it is because the softwareSerial library doesn't work with Leonardo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/software-serial

> Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 boards support change
> interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 10, 11, 12, 13,
> 14, 15, 50, 51, 52, 53, A8 (62), A9 (63), A10 (64), A11 (65), A12
> (66), A13 (67), A14 (68), A15 (69). Not all pins on the Leonardo and
> Micro boards support change interrupts, so only the following can be
> used for RX: 8, 9, 10, 11, 14 (MISO), 15 (SCK), 16 (MOSI).

So this `SoftwareSerial rSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX` won't work.

Also Arduino Leonardo has two hardware serials. I don't see why you would use SoftwareSerial here.